# How to output a number with two decimal places from a user defined function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a user defined function using Excel VBA. The function is as follows.

```
Function fetchNSV(storeCode As String) As Long
    Dim nsv As Double
    Dim storeCodeLower As String
    
    storeCodeLower = LCase(storeCode)
    
    Select Case storeCodeLower
        Case "eca3"
            nsv = 15.67
    
        Case Else
            nsv = "N/A"
    End Select

    fetchNSV = nsv
End Function
```

However the function outputs `16.00` instead of `15.67`. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: A Long can't have decimals per definition. Use Double.

Comment: Note: `nsv = "N/A"` means you are trying to put a `String` value into a `Long` which will error. It will also error if you use a `Double` - So you may want to re-think your function.

Answer (score 1):

Return a *Variant* that can hold both *text* as well as a *decimal* number:

```vb
Function fetchNSV(storeCode As String) As Variant
    
    Dim nsv As Variant
    Dim storeCodeLower As String
    
    storeCodeLower = LCase(storeCode)
    
    Select Case storeCodeLower
        Case "eca3"
            nsv = 15.67    
        Case Else
            nsv = "N/A"
    End Select

    fetchNSV = nsv

End Function
```

Comment: If `nsv = "N/A"` is meant to be the error value `#N/A` then it should be `CVErr(xlErrNA)` to make sure the cell contains a real error value and not just a text (that looks like an error value).

Answer (score 0):

So, change function data type from `Long` to `Double`.

```
Function fetchNSV(storeCode As String) As Double
```